# Wit.ai entities not recognized without "training"

Tags: artificial-intelligence, wit.ai

I have several entities in my Wit.ai app like for example countries with over hundred values. I created a story where I have 10 examples of a user message with just the country name and where I tell Wit.ai that this is a certain country value.

But the other country values are not recognized when I try them under "Understanding" Tests. I need to try every country there and then make the connection to the right value. I am using the "keywords-search-strategy" since I am looking for the exact value in the user message. But I have tried the others too.

Why is Wit.ai not recognizing all of the given values of my entity? Isnt this the easiest way when I am looking for the exact value?

I got several other entities too, where the situation is the same. Anyone an idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: What Wit entity type are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Trait search instead of Keyword.

Comment: I tried it. Not working. I also tried all values yesterday and connected them to the right entity if it wasn't recognized and still today some values are not recognized.

Comment: And it seems that with "trait" the Wit.ai also tries to recognize similar words. So words it knows are also recognized when they have typos. Only the exact words should be recognizes.